# Best way to store large objects/arrays for archiving, low access and search?

Tags: php, store

The project I'm working on collects data from 3rd party APIs (like Facebook, Twitter, etc). The data from these APIs is returned as objects or arrays, and we need a way to archive this data in case we want to access / read / process it later (later being months or more down the road) via PHP.

I was thinking about using AWS's DynamoDB and json_encode the arrays and create a record for each "item" (ex: a post on Facebook with all of its attributes as the array), but, I'm unsure if that's the best way to handle it. There are going to be thousands of "items" recorded every day, and we do need the ability to go back and read this data (via PHP) at a later point, while still attributing the data to a few values such as a user account, the item ID (ex: Facebook fan page ID, Twitter user account, etc.) and the timestamp the data was pulled, so we can grab specific items if necessary.

What would be the best way to save this data, mainly for archival purposes, but also retain the ability to find specific data if/when necessary? We need something that's fast (both at writes, and reads/queries/searches) and scalable that can handle a large amount of data over time. Suggestions and examples of proposed solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question; however, I'd say to take a look at this : https://sqlite.org/
Be sure to look at it was designed for because I'm not sure if it is scalable enough for your situation.